# X-axis taper problem

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, tronxy-p802

Tronxy P802M I believe. PLA. The calibration cube is tapered on one side of the X-axis only. Everything else looks good. The top is almost 1 mm narrower than the bottom, but only on X-axis.

[image: Photo of calibration cube with printing error]

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please provide a sharper image and put the measurements in the image or in words in the question. Is this the 20 mm calibration cube? So, is the top in X 19.0 mm? What temperatures did you use? Please [edit] the question, not comment, thanks!

Comment: Check whether your Z axis rods are the same distance apart at the bottom and the top of their travel.